# SQL Server: identify / extract multiple values (e.g. IDs) from a STRING to create a comma-separated list

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to identify/extract multiple ID's from a string; with the aim of then using the identified values to create a comma-separated list.

The string primarily contains "useless" text. However, some rows will contain either one or more 'IDs' that are useful and I would like to extract said IDs.

Every ID will have the same three-letter prefix ("EGG") followed by a five-digit numeric value (e.g. 12911).

For example, I have the following strings in a description field in my sample data (`TEXT_SAMPLE`):

|  | TEXT_SAMPLE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Today is a EGG01234 EGG12345 fine day EGG67891 |
| 2 | Blah Blah Blah |
| 3 | EGG01234, EGG12345 test test |

I would like the `OUTPUT` to be:

|  | TEXT_SAMPLE | OUTPUT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Today is a EGG01234 EGG12345 fine day EGG67891 | EGG01234,EGG12345,EGG67891 |
| 2 | Blah Blah Blah | null |
| 3 | EGG01234, EGG12345 test test | EGG01234,EGG12345 |

I appreciate it would be easier to do this via REGEX; but unfortunately, I am limited to SQL Server.

I have attempted the following but it's not quite right:

```
SELECT
    T1.TEXT_EXAMPLE,
    CASE
       WHEN T1.TEXT_EXAMPLE LIKE CONCAT ('%', 'EGG', '%')
          THEN SUBSTRING(T1.TEXT_EXAMPLE, PATINDEX('%EGG%', T1.TEXT_EXAMPLE), LEN(T1.TEXT_EXAMPLE))
          ELSE NULL
    END AS OUTPUT
FROM
    MSSQL_SAMPLE_DATA T1
```

Output:

|  | TEXT_SAMPLE | OUTPUT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Today is a EGG01234 EGG12345 fine day EGG67891 | EGG01234 EGG12345 fine day EGG67891 |
| 2 | Blah Blah Blah | null |
| 3 | EGG01234, EGG12345 test test | EGG01234, EGG12345 test test |

Please feel free to use the script below to `CREATE` a Table that contains some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #MSSQL_SAMPLE_DATA_TABLE 
(
    TEXT_EXAMPLE nvarchar NULL
)

INSERT INTO #MSSQL_SAMPLE_DATA_TABLE ( [TEXT_EXAMPLE])
VALUES ('Today is a EGG01234 EGG12345 fine day EGG67891'),  
       ('Blah Blah Blah'),  
       ('EGG01234, EGG12345 test test')
```

And when you've finished, the following will `DROP` the Table:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MSSQL_SAMPLE_DATA_TABLE') IS NOT NULL 
   DROP TABLE #MSSQL_SAMPLE_DATA_TABLE
```

Or, if you would rather use CTE:

```
WITH MSSQL_SAMPLE_DATA (TEXT_EXAMPLE) AS
(
       SELECT
              'Today is a EGG01234 EGG12345 fine day EGG67891'
       UNION
       SELECT
              'Blah Blah Blah'
       UNION
       SELECT
              'EGG01234, EGG12345 test test'
)
SELECT
       T1.*
FROM
       MSSQL_SAMPLE_DATA T1
```

Please let me know if you require additional information, etc.

Comment: Is exporting your table from SQL Server to a text file (and then importing into some other tool) an option here?  This is one ugly problem to try to tackle using SQL Server.

Comment: Seems like the *real* problem here is the design and the storage of "Englishy" sentences that you want to consume as denormalised data. The *real* solution is fix your design, if I am honest.

Comment: Hi @Larnu and Tim Biegeleisen, in the 'real' data, the full string does contain more meaningful, better-structured information (the examples I've provided are particularly nonsensical). That being said, for my immediate needs, it is (for the most part) redundant. I do however agree there are limits with how far we should take transformation and I always advise that data is fixed at source (which in this case, is the long-term plan. But for the interim, I need to explore alternative, short-term solutions).

Comment: Hi @Charlieface, yes; all IDs start with ‘EGG’ and are followed by a five-digit numeric value.

Comment: @Austin; thank you. My mentality is that if people are taking the time to help me, the very least I can do is to (*try* and) make it as easy/pain-free as possible for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `string_split()` and `string_agg()` to accomplish this:

```
select *
from MSSQL_SAMPLE_DATA_TABLE cross apply
    (select string_agg(s.value, ',') as eggs
     from string_split(translate(text_example, ',', ' '), ' ') s
     where s.value like 'EGG[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
    ) s;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=304aaa1feda65ee06dd4b1232df9fb55) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff; much appreciated. I will review later.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following query

```
SELECT T1.TEXT_EXAMPLE,REPLACE(T2.[OUTPUT],',,',',') 
FROM  MSSQL_SAMPLE_DATA_TABLE T1 LEFT JOIN
(SELECT TEXT_EXAMPLE,STRING_AGG(value,',') AS [OUTPUT]
  FROM MSSQL_SAMPLE_DATA_TABLE  
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(TEXT_EXAMPLE, ' ')
    WHERE value LIKE CONCAT('%', 'EGG', '%')
    GROUP BY TEXT_EXAMPLE) T2 ON t1.TEXT_EXAMPLE = T2.TEXT_EXAMPLE
```

result in [https://dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=25993b4acaf3c50a55fd10a0ac2c9b49)

Comment: Thank you @Maysam Asadi; much appreciated. I will review later.

Comment: The double-comma in the results from `'EGG01234, EGG12345 test test'` doesn't look right.